# Xamarin Forms Stopwatch Milliseconds Format

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using simple stopwatch in xamarin forms,
everything is ok but when I use lable to view it, it shows the milliseconds include (7) digits as follows:
00:00:00:0000000

how i can make it less or formatted it as I want?

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), () =>
            {
                lblText.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
                return true;


            });
```

Comment: You can put a format string in the `ToString()`

Comment: [Stopwatch.Elapsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed?view=net-5.0) is a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0). You can pass a format string to [TimeSpan.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=net-5.0) and format the value any way you want. You can use [standard TimeSpan format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) like `c`, `g`, `G` or a custom format string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format with `string.Format`.

```
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

[image]

**Update：**

Xaml:

```
  <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_result" FontSize="Large" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                x:Name="btn_Start"
                Clicked="btn_Start_Clicked"
                Text="Start" />
            <Button
                x:Name="btn_Stop"
                Clicked="btn_Stop_Clicked"
                Text="Stop" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
 private void btn_Start_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_Start.IsVisible = false;
        stopWatch.Start();

        btn_Stop.IsVisible = true;
    }

    private void btn_Stop_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds/10);

        lbl_result.Text = elapsedTime;
        btn_Start.IsVisible = true;
        btn_Stop.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

**Update2:**

If you wanna see the time running as real time, you could use Timer.

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_result" FontSize="Large" />
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
            x:Name="btn_Start"
            Clicked="btn_Start_Clicked"
            Text="Start" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn_Stop"
            Clicked="btn_Stop_Clicked"
            Text="Stop" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Timer timer;
    int hours = 0, mins = 0, secs = 0, milliseconds = 0;
    private void btn_Start_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1; // 1 milliseconds  
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed; ;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        milliseconds++;
        if (milliseconds >= 1000)
        {
            secs++;
            milliseconds = 0;
        }
        if (secs == 59)
        {
            mins++;
            secs = 0;

        }
        if (mins == 59)
        {
            hours++;
            mins = 0;
        }
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            lbl_result.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", hours, mins, secs, milliseconds / 10);
        });
    }

    private void btn_Stop_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the format is right but the stopwatch not working , freezing at 00:00:00.00

Comment: I provided my sample code. Please check my update.

Comment: thanks man it worked , still can't see the time running as real time , if you can help me see it running .. thanks again

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.

Comment: Great answer thanks